# How to change my site url structure in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My current *page-url* looks like the below,

```
http://localhost/testWP/?mode=home
```

but I want to make the url like the following:

```
http://localhost/testWP/mode/home
```

---

- How do I write an appropriate `.htaccess`-file to turn this into reality?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+testWP/?\?mode=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /testWP/mode/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^testWP/mode/(.+)$ /testWP/?mode=$1 [L]
```

Note that if you change your URL base (in your question it seems to be `/testWP/`), you'll need to adjust the rules to reflect any changes you make by replacing `testWP` with whatever is appropriate.